# How to keep whitespace when invoke web service with SOAP method

Tags: c#, soap, whitespace

I have a web service written by C#, assume that is http://www.mysvr.com/answer/sms.asmx. This service has a operations named "Hello", one variable named "cnt1", and I will transfer value to this variable.

If I use XML to read it, like:

```
XmlDocument xdoc = new XmlDocument();

xdoc.Load("http://www.mysvr.com/answer/sms.asmx/Hello?cnt1=abc");

return xdoc.ChildNodes[1].InnerXml;
```

I will get string "Hello_*_*_everybody". There are 5 white space between "Hello" and "everybody". I want to keep this whitespace.

But when I use SOAP to read it, like:

```
[System.Web.Services.Protocols.SoapDocumentMethodAttribute("http://tempuri.org/Hello",RequestNamespace="http://tempuri.org/",ResponseNamespace="http://tempuri.org/",Use=System.Web.Services.Description.SoapBindingUse.Literal,ParameterStyle=System.Web.Services.Protocols.SoapParameterStyle.Wrapped)]
public string Hello(string cnt1)
{
     object[] results = this.Invoke("Hello", new object[] {cnt});
     return ((string)(results[0]));            
}
```

I will get string "Hello everybody". There is only one whitespace between "Hello" and "everybody".

Problem: I want to use SOAP to call web service, and I want to keep 5 white space between "Hello" and "everybody".

Any one can help me to solve this problem? May I have to re-code web service, or add argument to SOAP to enable to read 5 white space?

Thanks many.

Answer (score 1):

Try including the "Hello     everybody" string within

```
"<![CDATA["    "]]>"
```

strings. Like:

```
<root>
    <welcome><![CDATA[Hello     everybody]]></welcome>
</root>
```